# Itext 5.x is not working with AbstracPdfView

Tags: spring-mvc, itext

I am trying to use itext 5.5.10 but i am not able to use it with the AbstractPdfView because AbstractPdfView must implement the method which contains parameters as document and pdfwriter of itext 2.1.7. Is there any way to use itext 5.x with spring MVC

Comment: Welcome to [so] and please see [ask]

Comment: What is AbstractPdfView and why is it still using iText 2.1.7? It must be a dead project because iTexr 2.1.7 dates from 2009 and the current iText version is 7 (not 5).

Comment: AbstractPdfView is used for converting the data into pdf view. I don't know why it is still using the parameters of iText 2.1.7. I know that the current iText version is 7 but I am not able to use both iText 7 and iText 5 with my Spring MVC project. Is there any way you can suggest me to use one of the iText 7 or iText 5 with my Spring MVC project